# F# On Server and Database

Tags: f#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I'm starting a new webapi Project

For domain implementation I m going to use F#.

To Store Data I m going to use Database, Which I haven't  decided.

**ORM**
if it will be C# I would be using Entity Framework with no question in my mind.

**But using F# + Entity Framework I have following questions**

1- Bcs of my domain is in F# all my Entities and Value Objects will be in F#. Does EF core will work with it ? (eg Discriminated Union)

2- if not what are different Options I have ?

3- What Options do u use?

feel free to share sample projects

I don't want to use **type providers** bcs I don't want to manage DB Manually (not at start).

Comment: I do not understand what the actual question is - are you trying to figure out how to store data in the project? If so, where do you want to store the data?

Comment: sorry please check it again i have edited it

Comment: You say "I'm going to use database" but then you say you do not want to use type providers because you don't want to manage a database. This seems contradictory to me. I would certainly use type providers for working with database..

Comment: instead of using type providers u can use ORMs where u don't  have to manually manage Database

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use EF with F#, though there's no support for DUs (what does a DU even look like in Sql Server/PostGres?) I do it in a pet project, but I have a ton of mappers that convert between the immutable records of my domain model and the mutable changed tracked entities. I don't necessarily believe this is the best approach. It may be possible to map a table to an F# record, but I'm not sure if there are significant advantages to that due to the loss of mutability, since EF uses change tracking to create updates. If you're doing a bunch of "get only" calls, dapper is significantly simpler and easier to use.

If you're trying to avoid directly managing a database, e.g. creating/editing tables/columns/PKs/FKs, there are a bunch of tools that make doing that easy, like Sql Server Management Studio or Navicat. I've rarely had to drop into SQL to tweak the schema. Combined with [mssql-scripter](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter) or `pgdump`, and versioning your DB is simple. I'm assuming that you're using MSSQL or PostGres, of course.

Comment: if there is sample project feel free to share

Comment: https://github.com/dharmaturtle/CardOverflow It currently uses PostGres, but if you step back through history far enough you'll find a point where I used MSSQL. EF is pretty cool, allowed me to switch databases in only 3 days. Feel free to open an issue if you have any questions - I'm pretty responsive.